# How to print a number sequence figure using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to write a program that prints out the following figure:

```
122333444455555
22333444455555
333444455555
444455555
55555
```

This is my code:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < a; b++)  
    {          
        System.out.print(a);
    }        
}
```

which prints out `122333444455555`

I need to triple nest my for loops, but I'm not sure where else to start. If I could get any hints/tips, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have over thought this. I would simplify things and use a different algorithm. Initiate a `String` and mutate it with one loop. Like,

```
String s = "122333444455555";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(s);
    s = s.substring(i + 1);
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
122333444455555
22333444455555
333444455555
444455555
55555
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){
    for (int b = a; b <= 5; b++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you had your answer, but I have some fun doing this LOL:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int aux = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
        if(i == 1) {
            System.out.print("1");
        } else if (i ==2){
            System.out.print("22");
        }else if (i ==3){
            System.out.print("333");
        }else if (i ==4){
            System.out.print("4444");
        }else if (i ==5){
            System.out.print("55555\n");
            if(aux != 5) {
                aux ++;
                i = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `for loops` I assume you meant at least two of them.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for(int k = i; k <= 5; k++) {
    System.out.print((k+"").repeat(k));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This method is nice,but only work in Java 11 or later version.

Comment: Thanks but it's not relevant?  The OP didn't specify.  We're already up to Java 16!    And `StringBuilder` only works in Java 5 or later. :)

Answer (score 0):

A more common solution about you issue:

**Codes**

```
private static void printStringSequence(int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = i; j < number; j++) {
            sb.append(generateRepeateSequence(j + 1));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}

private static String generateRepeateSequence(int number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        sb.append(number);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Test Output**

*printStringSequence(5);*

```
122333444455555
22333444455555
333444455555
444455555
55555
```

*printStringSequence(4);*

```
1223334444
223334444
3334444
4444
```